# Insert last created Id and use as parameter into another insert

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have two inserts into stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_Create_Slider 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @SliderId int, 
    @LanguageId int,
    @Photo varbinary(max),
    @Title varchar(250),
    @Description varchar(250),
    @IsDeleted bit = false
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

BEGIN TRY
INSERT INTO Store.Slider VALUES (@Photo)
INSERT INTO Store.SliderDetail VALUES (@SliderId,@LanguageId, @Title, @Description, @IsDeleted);
    return 1;
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

EXEC usp_Sql_Error_Codes 'usp_Create_Slider'
    return 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH

END
```

**Update**

**Store.Slider table:**

```
+----------+----------------+
| SliderId |      int       |
+----------+----------------+
| Photo    | varbinary(max) |
+----------+----------------+
```

**Store.SliderDetail table**

```
+----------------+--------------+
| SliderDetailId |     int      |
+----------------+--------------+
| SliderId       | int          |
| LanguageId     | int          |
| Title          | Varchar(255) |
| Description    | Varchar(255) |
| IsDeleted      | bit          |
+----------------+--------------+
```

that I want to do is to get `SliderId` from `Store.Slider` and use as parameter in second insert in SliderDetail. 
How can I achieve this? Regards

Comment: You need to specify the database you are using.

Comment: I added it @GordonLinoff

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. `sql` is just the *query language* - used by many RDBMS - but it's **not** a database system....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query to get the last inserted id from the auto increment column

```
LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

this should go after the `INSERT INTO Store.Slider VALUES (@Photo)` you can then assign the value it returns to `SliderId` or better still use it in the second insert query directly

```
INSERT INTO Store.SliderDetail VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),@LanguageId, @Title, @Description, @IsDeleted);
```

Comment: but how can I specify that LAST_INSERT_ID() is from Store.Slider table?

Comment: ok, for sql the column has to be `identity` then you can use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. see more about that from [this post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: yes, my column is not null primarykey and identity(1,1)

Comment: it always gets the id from the last insert query

Comment: but when I use  LAST_INSERT_ID() I get an error: 'LAST_INSERT_ID' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: do not use the last_insert_id() if it is not mysql, this should serve better `IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)`